# Clojure: invoking multiple arity functions

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, arity

I have a problem invoking the multiple arity function `printf` on `java.io.PrintWriter` (specifically, `System.out`).

```
user=> (.printf System/out (into-array Object ["foo"]))
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: printf for class java.io.PrintStream
clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
user=>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code attempts to call method `printf(Object[] arg)` of `java.io.PrintStream` class. But such method doesn't exist. Propably you want to call this one `printf(String format, Object ... args)` like this:

```
(.printf System/out "arg1: %s" (into-array Object ["foo"]))
=> #<PrintStream java.io.PrintStream@708e4544>
arg1: foo
```

Here `#<PrintStream java.io.PrintStream@708e4544>` is an object returning from `printf`.